# SQL to select data, insert into temp table then reselect data from temp table and insert again, until no data found

Tags: sql, while-loop

I've been trying to work out the best way to capture data from a table where data can be held as the parent and child, example as below.

| Parent ID | Child ID | Order Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B2 | 1 |
| A1 | B3 | 2 |
| A1 | B4 | 3 |
| B1 | C1 | 1 |
| B1 | C2 | 2 |
| B4 | D1 | 1 |
| C1 | E1 | 1 |
| D1 | F1 | 1 |

I'm trying to capture the links starting with a specific parent and then identifying the children and then searching the child code as a parent to identify any additional links, if that makes sense, until no more links are found.  So searching 'A1' above should end up showing the following.

| Parent ID | Child ID | Order Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B2 | 1 |
| A1 | B3 | 2 |
| A1 | B4 | 3 |
| B4 | D1 | 1 |
| D1 | F1 | 1 |

I was thinking about inserting the parent data into a temp table and then searching the child as the parent code to see if any data exists, add to the temp table and then search again, but I'm not sure if a loop can do this and if it can how to identify which parents/childs have already been searched.  Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
WITH Tree AS (
    SELECT 
        Orders.ChildId,
        Orders.ParentId,
        1 AS [Depth],
        CAST(Orders.ParentId + '|' +  Orders.ChildId AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) [Path],
        Orders.Orders
    FROM    Orders
    WHERE   Orders.ParentId = 'A1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        Orders.ChildId,
        Orders.ParentId,
        Tree.[Depth] + 1 [Depth],
        Tree.[Path] + '|' + Orders.ChildId [Path],
        Orders.Orders
    FROM        Tree
    INNER JOIN  Orders
    ON          Orders.ParentId = Tree.ChildId
    WHERE       '|' + Tree.[Path] + '|' NOT LIKE '%|' + Orders.ChildId + '|%'
    AND         Orders.ChildId <> Orders.ParentId
)
SELECT  ParentId, ChildId, Orders
FROM    Tree
```

This has loop detection built in which is why it's also adding a path and checking it.  Otherwise it could run forever if your data has parental loops in it.

Comment: Thank you Luke for the quick reply and code.  I'll run some testing later today and will let you know the outcome.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Luke.  I've been testing and all looks good, so just want to say thanks again for your help.

Comment: NP.  Glad you're up and running. 
 I think there's a button on here to mark this thread as answered.